# napi/eth%d-8193 takes > 30% CPU

Tags: network-interface, performance

I have recently upgraded my kernel. Now `napi/eth%d-8193` takes > 30% CPU:

```
top - 16:29:57 up 9 days,  4:16, 70 users,  load average: 5.48, 4.84, 5.00
Tasks: 1935 total,   2 running, 1906 sleeping,  25 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu(s): 22.8 us, 13.3 sy,  0.5 ni, 61.9 id,  1.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
GiB Mem :     31.2 total,      1.1 free,     21.8 used,      8.3 buff/cache
GiB Swap:    158.3 total,    135.5 free,     22.8 used.      2.7 avail Mem 
Change delay from 3.0 to 
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND            
2248606 tange     20   0 3248492 512252  48776 S  83.7   1.6 233:18.52 Isolated Web Co    
1567449 tange     20   0  794220 227564 191832 S  53.3   0.7 381:10.92 RDD Process        
1558648 tange     20   0   15.0g   1.1g 428420 S  40.8   3.6 588:56.31 firefox            
    228 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  39.9   0.0 687:19.55 napi/eth%d-8193
```

I have never had that before.

The system has 25 Mbit/s network I/O, so using > 30% CPU to move that seems crazy high. The system has earlier been able to move 1 Gbit/s. Now I can only get around 100 Mbit/s.

How can I get my earlier performance back?

```
$ uname -a
Linux aspire 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Try vanilla 5.19.6, if it's still broken, file a bug report at bugzilla.kernel.org